# Hibernate Query with conditions in a complex db structure

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

I have a complex database that's looking like this:

```
product *1 <-> n* inventory *n <-> 1* inventoryUser *1 <-> n* user
```

Now I would like to query e.g. all products where user.firstname = 'peter' in hql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figered out how to handle it:

```
Product as p join fetch p.inventories as i join fetch i.inventoryUser as iu join fetch iu.user as u where u.name=:name
```

Answer (score 2):

In your entities and mappings you should have references for each of these relations. And your HQL query will look like:

```
SELECT p FROM Product p, IN(p.inventory.inventoryUser) AS iu 
    WHERE iu.username=:username
```

Comment: hehe if it would only be that easy... I have tried this, but because of the fact that inventoryUser is a Collection Hibernate throws a 'QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection'

Comment: no, still getting: 'HibernateQueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [product0_.id.inventories] with element property reference [inventoryUser]'

Comment: @Bozho: what you wrote should work. but can you tell me why it wouldnt work just like this: FROM Product p, IN(p.inventory.inventoryUser) AS iu WHERE iu.username=:username (took me long time to figure out i must put  select in order this collection reference to work this way)

Comment: I haven't used the `"FROM X` syntax for a long time, so I don't really know.